# componentDidMount not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component that does not appear to be firing the `componentDidMount` event. The component is a parent that is accessed using react-router Link via another component.

here is my list component and the child components:

**CoursesPage**

```
import React from 'react';
import CourseList from './CourseList';
import CourseApi from '../../api/courseApi';

import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

class CoursesPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            courses: []
        };
        this.redirectToAddCoursePage = this.redirectToAddCoursePage.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        CourseApi.getAllCourses().then(coursesData => {
            this.setState({ courses: coursesData });
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    }

    redirectToAddCoursePage() { browserHistory.push('/course'); }

    render() {
        const courses = this.state.courses;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="page-header">
                    <h3>Courses</h3>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="New Course" className="btn btn-default btn-toolbar pull-right" onClick={this.redirectToAddCoursePage} />
                <div className="panel panel-default ">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                    <CourseList courses={courses} />
                </div>
            </div>        
        );
    }
}

export default CoursesPage;
```

**CourseListRow**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CourseListRow from './CourseListRow';

const CourseList = ({courses}) => {
    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Length</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                { courses.map(course => <CourseListRow key={course.CourseId} course={course} /> )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};

CourseList.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default CourseList;
```

**CourseListRow**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

const CourseListRow = ({course}) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td><Link to={'/course/' + course.CourseId}>{course.CourseId}</Link></td>
            <td>{course.Title}</td>
            <td>{course.Author.FirstName + ' ' + course.Author.LastName}</td>
        </tr>
    );
};

CourseListRow.propTypes = {
    course: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default CourseListRow;
```

**My routes**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import CoursesPage from './components/course/CoursesPage';
import ManageCoursePage from './components/course/ManageCoursePage';

export default (
    <Route path="/" components={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="courses" component={CoursesPage} />
        <Route path="course" component={ManageCoursePage} />
        <Route path="course/:id" component={ManageCoursePage} />
    </Route>
);
```

All of the above components work fine. However, when I click on the Link for a course in the CourseListRow component to route to the component below, the state for the course object is always empty. I put a debugger statement in the componentDidMount event and it never hits it, so this components CourseForm child component (not shown) never gets the course:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CourseForm from './CourseForm';
import {authorSelectData} from '../../selectors/selectors';
import CourseApi from '../../api/courseApi';
import AuthorApi from '../../api/authorApi';

export class ManageCoursePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            course: {},
            authors: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let id = this.props.params.id;
        if (id) {
            CourseApi.getCourse(id).then(courseData => {
                this.setState({ course: courseData });
            }).catch(error => {
                throw(error);
            });
        }

        AuthorApi.getAllAuthors().then(authorsData => {
            this.setState({
                authors: authorSelectData(authorsData)
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CourseForm 
                course={this.state.course}
                allAuthors={this.state.authors}
            />
        );
    }
}


ManageCoursePage.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};

export default ManageCoursePage;
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure why componentDidMount is not firing and populating the course state object. Any help is appreciated

**Follow up:**

I changed my render method of my parent (ManageCoursePage) component to the following, commenting out the CourseForm child compnonent:

```
render() {
    return (
        <h2>Hi {this.state.course.CourseId}</h2>
        /*<CourseForm 
            course={this.state.course}
            authors={this.state.authors}
            onChange={this.updateCourseState}
            onSave={this.saveCourse}
            onDelete={this.deleteCourse}
            onCancel={this.cancelChange}
            errors={this.state.errors}
            saving={this.state.saving}
            deleting={this.state.deleting}
        />*/
    );
}
```

This worked, I got "Hi 11". It appears for whatever reason my child component is not receiving the props from my parent. Could this be something to do with react router, that I am missing something? This has me really perplexed

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/702
My guess is that you are expecting the componentDidMount to be called on the route change, but if the component is already mounted it wont call it again

Comment: So `ManageCoursePage` is being rendered but `componentDidMount` is not being fired, correct? It's almost an impossibility for it to not be fire *at least* once, your 100% sure it's not an issue with your API call?

Comment: James - yes, that is the case. I put a debugger statement right at the top of the componentDidMount method and it doesn't hit it. If I change it to componentWillMount it gets there but it's too late, the state doesn't get to the child components.

Comment: Actually, I lied. If I hard code a test "course" object within the render method and pass that to the courseForm components, it hits the componentDidMount. I see render gets called before the componentDidMount,that appears to be my problem. There is nothing in the state course object until componentDidMount is called.

Comment: Ugh. Ok, the render being called before the componentDidMount is not my problem because calling this.setState is supposed to cause a rerender. I think I am going to study up more on the react component lifecycle.

Answer (score 4):

I think calling the getCourse in the componentWillReceiveProps and not in ComponentDidMount will solve your issue.

```js
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        var nextId = nextProps.params.id;
        if (nextId !== this.props.params.id) {
                  CourseApi.getCourse(nextId).then(courseData => {
                    this.setState({ course: courseData });
                }).catch(error => {
                    throw(error);
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I figured it out. This app was initially using redux, which I removed from the app. I thought since I was just learning react, jumping in with redux right away might make me miss how react really works.

Anyway, the problem was one line of code in my child component (not shown in the post). For what ever reason when using redux, I had to convert numbers to strings to get things to work:

```
value={ course.CourseId.toString() }
```

This was the line that was erring out.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Since the render method runs before componentDidMount and the course object properties were not set yet, tostring was trying to convert an undefined value. It blew up before componentDidMount was called, which is why I never hit it when debugging.

I don't know how I misinterpreted this error, but once I got rid of the toString() it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Here is how it happened and how I solved it.
I have parent component A that holds child component B.
I update A to generate a new child component B' instead of B (but B & B' are of the same type, content is different).
So A would trigger "componentDidMount", B would trigger "componentDidMount" but not B'.
It took me a moment to understand that React actually reuses the component and only changes its content instead of recreating one.

My solution was to add a "unique key" to B & B'

```
key={`whateverMakesIt_${Unique}`}
```

As simple as that my component B' start to trigger its call properly.